# fast decompression, lz4 doesn't reach advertised speeds

Tags: linux, performance, compression

I am transferring an lz4-compressed disk image (compression level 1) from a fast SMB network source (reaches 1 GB/s (not Gb/s)), but am experiencing relatively slow unpack speeds, nothing near the multiple gigabyte/s/core that are advertised. For my application, I'd like decompression to run a lot faster. CPU is an intel 9900x (10 cores), system is running Ubuntu 21.04, disk is an Intel 905p. My question is: how do i get my lz4 file to unpack faster, ideally at close to the network bandwidth?

I ran a bunch of timing benchmarks, showing speed of network, disk, etc. Here we go:

1. Network copy is fast:

   ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.lz4 > part3.ntfs.lz4
    7,85GiB [1,06GiB/s]
    real    0m9,304s
   ```
2. But unpacking file from network share runs at not even half that speed:

   ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > part3.ntfs
    7,85GiB [ 462MiB/s]
    real    0m18,131s
   ```
3. This does not seem to be because the file is accessed over the network, because unpacking from local disk runs hardly any faster:

   ```
    time pv -bae part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > part3.ntfs
    7,85GiB [ 534MiB/s] 
    real    0m16,192s
   ```

It may be something about disk access patterns, so lets try with a ramdisk, `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=25g tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`

4. Copying to the ramdisk is plenty fast:

   ```
    time pv -bae part3.ntfs.lz4 > /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs.lz4
    7,85GiB [3,05GiB/s] 
    real    0m2,575s
   ```
5. Unpacking to the ramdisk is however not much faster than unpacking to normal disk and (importantly), slower than straight copy of file over the network:

   ```
    time pv -bae part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs
    7,85GiB [ 725MiB/s]
    real    0m11,082s
   ```
6. Unpacking file from network to ramdisk is slower than from local disk:

   ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs
    7,85GiB [ 580MiB/s] 
    real    0m13,856s
   ```
7. And unpacking file from ramdisk to local disk is only about as fast as unpacking from and to local disk (see 3. above):

   ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > part3.ntfs
    7,85GiB [ 514MiB/s] 
    real    0m16,518s
   ```
8. unpack from disk to /dev/null:

   ```
    time pv -bae part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > /dev/null
    7,85GiB [1,01GiB/s]
    real    0m7,773s
   ```
9. unpack from network to /dev/null:

   ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > /dev/null
    7,85GiB [ 713MiB/s]
    real    0m11,275s
   ```
10. unpack from ramdisk to /dev/null:

    ```
    time pv -bae /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs.lz4 | lz4 -c -d > /dev/null
    7,85GiB [1003MiB/s]
    real    0m8,017s
    ```

Conclusions i draw from this is that it may be something about the way in which data gets written to disk that is the biggest bottleneck (compare 3 and 7), while also reading patterns are not ideal (compare 5 to 4). The network adds some additional overhead (compare 2 to 3, 5 to 6, and 8 to 9), but support much faster performance than i am currently observing (compare 9 to 2) .

For good measure, here is a in-memory benchmark with the same file:

```
    lz4 -b1 part3.ntfs 
    File(s) bigger than LZ4's max input size; testing 2016 MB only...
     1#part3.ntfs        :2113929216 ->1403663863 (1.506), 992.3 MB/s ,4881.8 MB/s
```

What can i do to speed up decompression?

## Update

After discussion below, i have found that the [lizard](https://github.com/inikep/lizard) algorithm offers much better performance, when run with multithreading. As the lizard repository itself does not offer that, i had to resort to building up to date 7zip from the 7zip_21.02 branch from [here](https://github.com/jinfeihan57/p7zip). Performance i then get with a file compressed with level 11:

```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.7z | ./7zz e -si -so -tlizard > /dev/null
    7,70GiB [1,05GiB/s]
    real    0m7,888s
```

However, when writing to disk instead of `/dev/null`, performance is no better than before:

```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3.ntfs.7z | ./7zz e -si -so -tlizard > part3.ntfs
    7,70GiB [ 405MiB/s] 
    real    0m20,392s
```

The same is also true when using a much higher compression level (-mx=29), where we see its fills the whole network pipe again when writing to /dev/null, but takes about the same total time when unpacking to disk. When unpacking to ramdisk it reaches much better performance again. Is it a disk write problem?

```
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3-29.ntfs.7z | ./7zz e -si -so -tlizard > /dev/null
    6,24GiB [1,05GiB/s] 
    real    0m5,961s
    
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3-29.ntfs.7z | ./7zz e -si -so -tlizard > part3.ntfs
    6,24GiB [ 331MiB/s] 
    real    0m20,338s
    
    time pv -bae /mnt/test/part3-29.ntfs.7z | ./7zz e -si -so -tlizard > /mnt/ramdisk/part3.ntfs
    6,24GiB [ 684MiB/s]
    real    0m9,776s
```

Comment: If you really want to test the speed impact of unpacking vs not unpacking, you _must_ discard the output (`> /dev/null`). Everything else means other mechanisms (local storage I/O, ramdisks, …) are involved. // Also keep in mind that LZ4 is limited by single-core performance.

Comment: You would want to use the faster (lower compression) settings of the lz4 compressor. What settings are you using? Have you tried different compressor algorithms? https://askubuntu.com/questions/258202/multi-core-compression-tools

Comment: @DanielB: thanks, i have added cases 8-10 with these results in there.

Comment: @Mokubai, I used compression level 1, which should be fastest. I'll investigate other algorithms now.

Comment: @Mokubai: wauw, that was a bit of a rabbit hole. zstd and pixz (multithreaded) yielded very similar performance. lizard did the trick (runs at line-speed!), but required compiling latest branch from https://github.com/jinfeihan57/p7zip.git manually

Comment: @Mokubai, wait, i was a bit too fast. It does line-speed when unpacking to /dev/null, not when unpacking to disk. I'll update the question